# How to design a layout like this: one box on top and two bottom covering the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I want 3 section one cover half part of the screen to show image slider and in half part, there is two section right now that part I'm done but now I want to add half part of the screen on top but it does not show image slider section, please help me.

right now my code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            color: white;
        }

        .split {
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        .left {
            left: 0;
            background-color: #ff6a00;
        }

        .right {
            right: 0;
            background-color: #ffd800;
        }

        .centered {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align: center;
        }

            .centered img {
                width: 150px;
                border-radius: 50%;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="split left">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>Blood Donor</h2>
                <p><a href="../BloodDonor/Registration/Registration.aspx">Go To Registration</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="split right">
            <div class="centered">
                <h2>Blood Seeker</h2>
                <p><a href="../BloodSeeker/Registration/Registration.aspx">Go To Registration</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

please help me,
Thank You for your time.

Comment: Take a look at [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Comment: @31piy No. Flexbox is for 1D positioning. Have a look at the 2D version of Flexbox, [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation with flex:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slider {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.link {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slider">Image slider</div>
  <div class="bottom-wrap">
    <div class="link">Page Link</div>
    <div class="link">Page Link</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/gazdagergo/pen/EexMvq)

Comment: As I said above, Flexbox is mainly for 1D positioning. Have a look at the 2D version of Flexbox, [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy using grid then is quite easy. You just need to setup a grid which with two columns and two rows.

Here is a link to a codepen, there are some other styles to make it a little easier to see what is going on but you only need to pay attention to the grid css attributes.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  height: 50vh;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-slider {
  background: magenta;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.page-link-1 {
  background: red;
}

.page-link-2 {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-slider">Image Slider</div>
  <div class="page-link-1">Page Link 1</div>
  <div class="page-link-2">Page Link 2</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tmcnicol/pen/PdoLpm/

Answer (score 1):

He's a simple layout using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) (the 2D version of Flexbox):

```css
.main {
  display: inline-grid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  border: green solid 2px;
}
.main .level1 {
  border: blue solid 2px;
  display: flex;
}
.main .level1 .level2 {
  border: red solid 2px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="level1"></div>
  <div class="level1">
    <div class="level2"></div>
    <div class="level2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```